# Microsoft ACE Text Driver converts numbers to dates

Tags: excel, vba, csv, parsing

I am trying to process huge CSV (~165 MB, ~500K rows) in Excel and decided to use ACE Text Driver. I have already got to know that I need to [create special section.ini file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?#main) next to program file. So far so good.
Say, I have following CSV:

```
ID;VAL1
JSNT;6,00
```

*Section.ini* file:

```
[test.csv]
Format=Delimited(;)
ColNameHeader=True
```

VBA code:

```
Sub GetEntries()

    Dim file_path$, conn_string$, sql$
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    
    conn_string = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                  "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\;" & _
                  "Extended Properties=Text;"
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [test.csv];"
    
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open sql, conn_string, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
    wksOutput.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

This code **works**, but take a look at the result:
[image: AceTextDriverConvertsNumberToDate]

In other words, Text Driver converted number into date! I thought that this was something about Excel with its conversions twists, but I made sure that the reason was Text Driver. Everything is simple - I just checked `Type` property of this field - and it was `adDate` (7). So, Excel had nothing to do with it.
But the page about section.ini says that I can set field type manually, and so I added this line into section.ini:

```
Col2=VAL1 Double
```

`Col2` means the second field and `Double` is the type of that field. But... it fails to work, too! 
After some tests I have discovered the following. The number is converted to date, if:

1. The number before decimal point is between 0 and 23 (including)
2. The number after decimal point is between 00 and 59 (including)
   As you can see, number `6,00` fits this condition, so it's converted to date.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Or I do something wrong?

### UPDATE

As @shrivallabha.redij noted, I could set the type of receiving columns as Text. But it's not a solution because I can't know beforehand *which* columns could behave this way.

Comment: On excel what format has the cell? General? Text? Date?

Comment: @Damian It's General, but as I said in question - it has nothing to do with it, because field's type is `adDate`.

Comment: As I understand it, if you don't specify data type then ACE engine guesses the Data type by the first data row. I'd suggest importing column as `Text` and then you can fix it in Excel post-import. I am sure there must be better and elegant way of doing it.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Setting Excel column's type to Text *does* work, but it's not, as you said, elegant way - just because I don't know which value and in which column it will convert number to date.. Actually, as I wrote in question, I *can* set field's type, but this doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: To paraphrase an old adage: some people, when they are presented with CSV, think "I know, I'll use the ACE driver". Now they have two problems. I'd suggest using any number of more robust ways to parse CSV (like PowerShell's `Import-Csv`), combined with any number of more robust ways to generate Excel sheets (like [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/4.0.9), disclaimer: no personal experience). For sufficiently large data sets, using SQL Server (Express) is another option worth considering; Excel interfaces with that well.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for suggestions, but this should be stand-alone program - be it Excel macros or C# app (for instance). Options like SQL Server don't fit this scenario. Moreover, this is my first experience with ACE driver - I did never use it. And do you have explanation why code doesn't work? Did I miss something? Or this is just well-known bug?

Comment: The ACE driver is pretty notorious for guessing at data types and getting it wrong (to be fair, it has nothing to go on other than the textual data of the CSV, so it's just not possible to always get it *right*). You can almost always get it to eventually do what you want/work around things, but IMO the fuss just isn't worth it. I prefer to avoid it whenever I can in favor of code that's predictable. For standalone code, there are better options for parsing CSV -- for .NET in particular, try the ever popular [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/).

Comment: I don't think you missed something. It looks more like a bug due to some implicit conversion of certain data type. We had a discussion on Chandoo.org forum (https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/ado-connection-csv-issue-with-mixed-data-type.34097/) on ACE OLEDB but we were looking at a different issue. But somehow I think there are not many tricks to be tried with this option.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for input! Now I won't mess with wrong guy. 

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Thanks for info! Gonna dig further. 

Comment: I do not know if it is related with your problem, but I would avoid the `ID` at the beginning of the `.csv` file: Excel's parser, in name of backward compatibility, tends to interpret such files as being in (now long-forgotten) SYLK format! They even had a KB page about this: [Q323626](https://web.archive.org/web/20080327141809/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323626)

Comment: @Q323626 Thanks for tip! I have developed another solution (C#) - with [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser). 